# Using the Same Argument File for Different Targets in Xcode C++

Tags: c++, xcode, parameter-passing, file-management, xcode-build-settings

I am new to Xcode and C++.For my project, I have created two different targets that utilize the same argument files containing the data for my projects (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kva6G.png)
I have set the scheme for each target's folder as the directory for each target. I want to pass data_500k.csv and operations.txt as arguments to both the array and file_IO target's main.cpp files.

When I added the data files into the src folder, the code ran flawlessly. However, I do not want to place each data file into the src folder and repeat the process for each target.
As in the photo, when I run the code, main.cpp couldn't open the data files.

When I add the test folder to each target's directory, it didn't work. But, when I added the data files from the test folder into the src folder, the code ran flawlessly. However, I do not want to place each data file into the src folder and repeat the process for each target. I tried changing the working directory of the targets to the DataStructure directory, but it still did not work.
I am seeking guidance on which settings I need to modify to ensure the project runs as expected without manually moving files around. Thank you.